# Extract a row while looking for a string in a csv file

Tags: python, pandas, csv, extract

I have a CSV file including 2 million rows and 2 million columns. One of the columns is the date and I want to extract all the rows which the date columns contain a "Monday" as a string, how can I do it? I can also change the date into the number format (mm/dd/yyyy) and then find all the rows (including their columns) which indicate a Monday.

Comment: "2 million rows and 2 million columns"... Are you sure?

Comment: Something like `df.loc[df['date'].eq("Monday")]`?

Comment: For these many columns/rows I will upload it to a database and query it

Answer (score 1):

For future reference, it is best practice to pose your question with the minimum reproducible code. I'm new here as well, so, don't sweat it!

To answer your question, you can pass a condition into a DataFrame on reassignment. I believe this is the most direct way of accomplishing your goal.

```
df = df['monday' in df['Date'].str.lower]
```

This answer filters the dataframe so that only rows containing the word "Monday" remain. Notice, calling .lower() directly on the df['Date'] will yield a type error, which is why it is imperative you first cast to a string. Of course, if you know the case of every occurrence of the word "Monday", calling .lower() isn't necessary in the first place.

Note, if you want to use this approach the check multiple conditions, you must used the bitwise operators (&, |, ^). As the boolean operators (and, or) will yield a type error.

Comment: You explain your approach quite well, but I think the code syntax should be slightly different to get the intended effect, namely: `df = df[df['Date'].str.lower().str.contains('monday')]`

Comment: @Xukrao I guess I thought my approach was a bit more pythonic, it's something I see quite often. However, your answer does appear more performative, and may be more helpful for somebody who is just becoming familiar with Pandas. Thanks!